# Generating a table of squares and square roots up to 100

Tags: list-manipulation, output-formatting, code-request

I want to generate a table of roots and perfect squares similar to the image, but I can't find the right code, I have searched the forum for something that works for me without favorable results. Can someone help me?

[image]

```
Print["Cuadrados de los números hasta 100"]
Print["================================="]


columnas = 10;
rango = Range[100];
cuadrados = Map[#^2 &, rango];
grupos = Partition[cuadrados, columnas];


Map[Print[StringForm["``^2 = ``", #[[1]], #[[2]]]] &, Transpose[{rango, cuadrados}]];
```

Answer (score 7):

```
$Version

(* "13.2.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (January 27, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

nmax = 100;

Row[
 Grid[#, Frame -> All] & /@
  Partition[
   Table[
    {
     StringForm["``=``", ToString[n]^2, n^2],
     StringForm["``=``", Sqrt[ToString[n^2]], n]},
    {n, nmax}],
   25]]
```

[image]

Comment: ,wow ,it was easy, but what broke my head and you wrote it in one fell swoop, thanks

Comment: Quick question to @BobHanlon:  Why must the order be `StringForm["``=``", ToString[n]^2, n^2]` when it would seem it should be instead `StringForm[ToString[n]^2, "``=``", n^2]`?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork - See the documentation. The first argument to `StringForm` is the "controlstring` (i.e., template) to be filled by the subsequent arguments.